# Will Crontab reload it's configuration just be editing the crontab file?

Tags: cron

Will Crontab reload it's configuration just be editing the Crontab file? will the crontab just change After I edit the crontab file or I will have  to run some command in order to reload configuration?

Comment: "Will I need to restart the server after saving the cron job in the crontab file before it will start working?" -> "No it'll start working straight away (well, the next possible scheduled time)."

Comment: You need to save the crontab *and* exit the editor. Only then will the crontab be reloaded.

Comment: If you edit the crontab file with `crontab -e`  .. yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will, nothing else to do, just edit the crontab file and save it, it takes effect immediately.